# missing EOF session execute cql query using datastax driver

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

I am running Java datastax driver to execute cql query to create schema and table(s) together in one query. And receiving EOF exception as below.

```
session.execute("CREATE KEYSPACE testkeyspace WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '3' } AND DURABLE_WRITES = true;"+
            "CREATE TABLE testkeyspace.users (" +
            "    name text," +
            "    birth_year int," +
            "    gender text," +
            "    PRIMARY KEY (name)" +
            ") WITH read_repair_chance = 0.0" +
            "   AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1" +
            "   AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000" +
            "   AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01" +
            "   AND caching = { 'keys' : 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition' : 'NONE' }" +
            "   AND comment = ''" +
            "   AND compaction = { 'class' : 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy' }" +
            "   AND compression = { 'sstable_compression' : 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor' }" +
            "   AND default_time_to_live = 0" +
            "   AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE'" +
            "   AND min_index_interval = 128" +
            "   AND max_index_interval = 2048;");
```

Exception Trace

```
Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 1:159 missing EOF at 'CREATE' (...} AND DURABLE_WRITES = true;[CREATE] TABLE...)
at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError.copy(SyntaxError.java:58)
at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError.copy(SyntaxError.java:24)
at com.datastax.driver.core.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:37)
at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:245)
at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:63)
at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:39)
at com.example.helloworld.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:58)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 1:159 missing EOF at 'CREATE' (...} AND DURABLE_WRITES = true;[CREATE] TABLE...)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:132)
at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.onSet(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:179)
at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:184)
at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.access$2500(RequestHandler.java:43)
at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:798)
at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.onSet(RequestHandler.java:617)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:1005)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:928)
at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:318)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:304)
at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:318)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:304)
at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:318)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:304)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:263)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:318)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:304)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate the two statements into distinct calls to `session.execute`.

The way the native protocol is designed, each request execution corresponds to one statement. There are batch execution requests that can contain multiple statements, but I'm not sure it makes a lot of sense with schema DDL. The driver actually has some schema agreement polling that happens after each schema change, to make sure references to the new element succeed on any host after the request completes.

Comment: Is there a work around? To execute all statements in one call?

Comment: I expanded my answer. What is your concern about executing two DDL statements serially?

Comment: I am dumping the schema for all keyspaces during backup phase in one file, so I want a way to execute all DDL statements in the file (create keyspace and column family) to execute in one query rather than parsing each statement in file and executing serially.

Comment: `cqlsh -f` can take input from a file like that.
http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/cqlsh.html
It does the parsing for you. There is no way around parsing as you describe.

Comment: Is there a ticket open to add an endpoint to support executing from a file or parsing String query with multiple statements for future release?

Comment: There is one here that was previously declined: https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-170